# gnu parallel and grep 'no such file or directory'

Tags: parallel-processing, grep, gnu

I have a directory with a lot of subdirs containing 1+million xml files.
I'd like to search for xml files with a certain element in it. 
This can be done by a grep.
I'd like to run it in parallel so I came up with the following based upon the parallel manual.

```
find . -type f | parallel -j 30 grep -roPlHn "<ce:abstract.*ce:figure.*abstract>" {}
```

But for some reason this doesnt work and it returns

```
/bin/sh: ce:abstract.*ce:figure.*abstract: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the ">"

```
... grep "<ce:abstract.*ce:figure.*abstract\>" ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue, always a bit unclear when to escape or not in a pipe.

Comment: Me too! I just start with a small search string and keep adding characters till it stops working !!! :-)